# Webstorm npm автоматическое добавление пакетов в package.json

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Народ, подскажите плиз, как автоматически можно обновить package.json при установке новых пакетов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новые пакеты я добавляю через терминал. Зависимости в глобальном package.json мне нужны для быстрой загрузки модулей на рабочем сервере. Уверен, что должен быть способ, как их автоматически ставить или из списка просто выбирать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы ставите новый пакет через терминал, вы можете дописать опцию --save. В таком случае пакет установится и будут прописаны зависимости в `package.json`.
Кроме того, имеются дополнительные опции `--save-dev` и `--save-optional`, которые занесут зависимости устанавливаемого пакета в `devDependencies` и `optionalDependencies`, соответственно.

Пример:

```
    npm install sax --save
    npm install node-tap --save-dev
    npm install dtrace-provider --save-optional
```

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) об `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

> как автоматически можно обновить package.json

В webstorme есть такая штука для работы с nmp, с вашим package.json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]